# Issue with displaying time using gmstrftime

Tags: php

when i am trying to print 160000 in gmstrftime.it results 20:26 but for 80000 it gives 22:13. i am not sure why this happening.Is their any kind of limit for gmstrftime?

```
echo gmstrftime('%H:%M', 160000);
```

it gives 20:26.

```
echo gmstrftime('%H:%M', 80000);
```

it gives 22:13

Comment: The second argument is a *UNIX timestamp*, not "160000" for "16:00:00".

Comment: @deceze : so what is the solution for this. because i am saving timestamp as integer in database and in front end i am doing some calculation on time stamp and print final output.

Answer (score 0):

Just as deceze pointed out the second arg is the epoch or unix time. Number of seconds since 1970 January 1 00:00.  If you leave the second arg out you will get the current time.

```
<?php
  $time1 = strtotime("2014-02-03 20:26");
  echo "First time (".date('c', $time1).") in epoch: $time1\n";
  echo gmstrftime('%H:%M', $time1)."\n";
  $time2 = strtotime("2014-02-03 22:13");
  echo "Second time (".date('c', $time2).") in epoch: $time2\n";
  echo gmstrftime('%H:%M', $time2)."\n\n";

?>
```

Plug in different dates for $time1 and $time2 to see the epoch time.

Answer (score 0):

`160000` is not a timestamp in any way that PHP (or other common systems) define a timestamp. What you have is merely a time of day expressed in "military time" stored as an integer. So first of all, any `gm` function is likely not what you want to use, since you are missing timezone information from this "timestamp" to begin with, hence conversion to GM time is ambiguous if not impossible.

The best you may be able to do is:

```
$timestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat('His', sprintf('%06d', 160000))->format('U');
echo strftime('%H:%M', $timestamp);
```

Comment: it is giving error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$'